# How to implement the facet grid feature using the ggfortify library on a time series data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, facet-grid, ggfortify

I am using `RStudio` and I have a `time series` data (`ts` object) called `data1`.

Here is how `data1` looks:

```
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2014 135 172 179 189 212  47 301 183 247 292 280 325
2015 471 243 386 235 388 257 344 526 363 261 189 173
2016 272 267 197 217 393 299 343 341 315 305 384 497
```

To plot the above, I have run this code:

```
plot (data1)
```

and I get the following plot:

[image: figure 1]

I want to have a plot that is broken by Year and I was thinking of implementing the `facet_grid` feature found in `ggplot2` but since my data is a `ts` object, I can't use `ggplot2` directly on it.

After some research, I've found that the `ggfortify` library works with `ts` objects. However, I am having a hard time trying to figure out to use the `facet_grid` feature with it.

My aim to is to plot something like below from my `ts` data:

[image: figure 2]

'Female'and 'Male' will be replaced by the Years 2014, 2015 and 2016. The X-axis will be the Months (Jan, Feb, Mar, and so on) and the y-axis will be the values in the `ts` file . I would prefer a line plot rather than a dot plot.

Am I on the right track here or is there another way of approaching this problem?

Comment: There are many examples on SO how to `reshape` your data and plot facets with `ggplot2`. PS: In your case I would use `geom_line(aes(color = factor(year)))` instead of facets.

Comment: I know I can reshape my data and use ggplot2. My point here is whether I can do it without reshaping the data and make use of ggfortify.

Comment: Anyone who gave minus marks did not understand the purpose of my question. I think it is clear in the title of the question that I am looking for a solution on how to make this work on a ts file. It's not about reshaping the data.

Comment: Have a look at `?ggplot2::autoplot`. You might try `library(lubridate); autoplot(data1) + facet_grid(. ~ year(Index), scales = "free_x")`

Comment: @markus Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for! Please post as an answer and I'll give my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ggplot2::autoplot`. I will use `AirPassengers` data as an example.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
autoplot(AirPassengers) + 
 facet_grid(. ~ year(Index), scales = "free_x") + 
 scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b")
```

[image]